# Android mark message as read not working properly

Tags: android, sms

I am building small android application in which I am reading incoming message and I want to mark it as read message. For that I have added required permissions and also added receive for listening incoming messages.Everything is working fine except mark it as read process. I tried it in following ways:

```
private void markMessageRead(Context context, String number, String body) {

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    try{

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            Debug.print("inside mark read before if ------ ");
            Debug.print(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"))+"  "+number);
            Debug.print(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("read"))+"  ");
            Debug.print(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"))+"  "+body);


            if ((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address")).equals(number)) && (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("read")) == 0)) {
                if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body")).startsWith(body)) {

                    Debug.print("inside read message inside if ... ");
                    String SmsMessageId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put("read", true);
                    context.getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values, "_id=" + SmsMessageId, null);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
}

//inside receiver side ... 
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    mContext = context;
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        markMessageRead(mContext, message.getOriginatingAddress(), message.getMessageBody());
                    }
                }, 2000);
}
```

Everything is working fine without any error. Only thing it is not marking my message as read message. Am I doing anything wrong. Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: Make your app the default SMS app
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html